# php variable inside foreach loop not working

Tags: php, foreach

I can't really understand why the following is not working. 
I have a variable set as follows:

```
$baseUSD = ($baseamount/$rateUSD);
```

And a foreach loop as follows:

```
foreach($rates as $key => $value) 
{  
$stmt2->bindValue(':currency', $key);
$stmt2->bindValue(':exchangerate', ($value * $baseUSD) );
```

The `($value * $baseUSD)` is not working inside the foreach loop.

I tried the following too, without any output:

```
foreach($rates as $key => $value) 
{  
echo $baseUSD;
```

If i explicity state the value as follows, it is echoing the value:

```
foreach($rates as $key => $value) 
{  
echo 1.5678;
```

I am echoing the value properly in:

```
$baseUSD = ($baseamount/$rateUSD);
```

So what is going wrong?? I am unable to understand. Maybe as a php newbie i am doing something wrong??

Edit: Resolved. I carelessly put the `$baseUSD = ($baseamount/$rateUSD);`inside a condition.

Comment: $baseUSD = [$baseamount/$rateUSD]; baseusd should be inarray, not in an string variable

Comment: @whoami $stmt2->bindValue(':exchangerate', ($value*$baseUSD)); All values inserted in DB is 0.0000 ??  Not working ??

Comment: $baseUSD = floatval($baseamount/$rateUSD); 
$baseINR = [$baseamount/$rateINR];
Nothing works ???

Comment: You're going to have to actually add your code - seems like you're using `->bindValue()` inside a foreach, but it's impossible to say if that's a useful thing to do if we don't know what's around the `bindValue` call. Maybe you're rebinding the value for each element in your `foreach` and just invoking the statement once, or these live in different scopes - Please add a complete, reproducible example.

Comment: @ MatsLindh  Edited my original post and added full code..Seems like it is something related to scope..

Comment: Did you tried calculating exchange rates as another variable and passed in bind value?

Comment: Yes..will work. But i am unable to multiply with my value.

Comment: And with bindValue, we can pass both values and variables, and it is not working ??

Comment: Will you share the rates php array output ? Also sample base amount value.

Comment: @NithyanandhanM  Array ( [AED] => 3.673097 [AFN] => 68.222 [ALL] => 113.105 [AMD] => 481.23 [ANG] => ..... ) 

$baseamount = 1;

Comment: Oh!! Sorry..I had put the $baseUSD = round(($baseamount/$rateUSD),4); inside a condition. My fault that i did not check it. How stupid i am. Sorry to all of you for the trouble. Please forgive my carelessness.

Comment: Please enable proper PHP error reporting, so that PHP can notify you of such mistakes by itself in the future.

Comment: @NithyanandhanM I have voted to close this question as the trouble was coming from a condition that was not included in the post.  The OP will be able to delete this question if you delete your answer (saving moderator time).